# MySQL query with PHP variable in it

Tags: php, mysql

```
A)$getDetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `OnlineRequests` WHERE `OSR_CODE`='".$code."'");

B)$getDetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `OnlineRequests` WHERE `OSR_CODE`='oooqhqxrcglm3jn6xd2lseq43nb3cq'");
```

It's PHP. B works but A doesn't. WHY? Syntax error? I feel like I've tried everything possible...

Comment: what's the error being thrown?

Comment: Lack of database escaping? Did you check `mysql_error()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: But sometimes I got "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Comment: Okay, and what was `$code` when you got that? please provide enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @mario it's not a duplicate but maybe the future problem.

Comment: check your variable isn't $code = "'oooqhqxrcglm3jn6xd2lseq43nb3cq'"; because that would make the query value look like this ''oooqhqxrcglm3jn6xd2lseq43nb3cq''

Comment: Put your query in a variable: $query="SELECT * FROM `OnlineRequests` WHERE `OSR_CODE`='".$code."'"; and then echo the query. Copy the query and run it in mysql directly and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do MySQL Queries I don't use `OSR_CODE=".$random_variable."`
I use `OSR_CODE='$random_variable'` so just use quotes around it opposite of the containing quotes, see if that works.  Just a suggestion, works for me.

Edit:
Try `$getDetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`OnlineRequests`WHERE`OSR_CODE`='.$code.'");`
??

Comment: Normally in situations like this it's something obvious, this kind of stuff happens to me all the time.  Check the variable name, check everything that goes into the variable.  Also try to turn some error reporting on.

Comment: GASP! That was it, it was something that went into the variable, something really stupid. I feel like an idiot because I've been trying for hours...

Comment: Ha!  It's cool it happens to all of us!

Answer (score -1):

To make A work, use

```
$getDetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `OnlineRequests` WHERE `OSR_CODE`=\"$code\"");
```

The problem is the single quotes.

Comment: Nope, single quotes are for SQL strings. MySQL also supports double quotes, but only if it runs in non-ansi mode.

Comment: I think that should work.Because of the single quotes,the value of $code is not substituted.

Comment: $getDetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `OnlineRequests` WHERE `OSR_CODE`LIKE \"$code\""); Another Try from my side